# how we can play audio with highlight in angularjs with timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, json

I am working on an Angular JS project , I am newbie in this technology . I have received an assignment from my boss .

> Assignment is :

1 . There is a html file with the text "This is a Burger" .

2 . I have a Audio(.mp3) file with the sound "This is a Burger" .

> What I want :

When Audio play then the text "This is Burger" should **high light** word by word .

Here is what I have done to achieve above task .

```
  $scope.audioplay=function(){
         var qIndex = $scope.qIndex; 
             $scope.QuestionAnswer=$scope.arrQuestion[qIndex][0];
             $scope.QuestionAudio=$scope.arrQuestion[qIndex][1];
             $scope.QuestionAudiodelay=$scope.arrQuestion[qIndex][2]; 
             $scope.Questionaudiotimeline=$scope.arrQuestion[qIndex][3];
             //console.log($scope.QuestionAnswer); console.log($scope.QuestionAudio);
             //console.log($scope.QuestionAudiodelay);
             //console.log($scope.arrOptionsId);

      $scope.QuestionAnswerArray = $scope.QuestionAnswer.split(' '); //alert($scope.QuestionAnswerArray.length);
      $scope.allAnswerWithSpan = {}; 
        for (var i = 0; i <$scope.QuestionAnswerArray.length; i++) {
                $scope.addanswer[i] = '<span id='+i+'>' +$scope.QuestionAnswerArray[i]+ '</span>'; 
                 console.log($scope.addanswer[i] );
          } 
         // alert($scope.Questionaudiotimeline.split(','));
           $scope.allAnswerWithSpan = $scope.addanswer.join(" ");
           //$scope.allAnswerWithSpan.addClass(element, 'fadeInDown');
        $scope.audioIndex = 0;
        $scope.playAudio(0);  
        /*$scope.audio =new Audio($scope.QuestionAudio);
        $scope.audio.play();
          $scope.audio.onended = function() { 
                $scope.audioIndex += 1;alert($scope.audioIndex);
                $scope.playAudio($scope.audioIndex); 
            }; */  
         var dumb = function (id) {
          var queryResult = $document[0].getElementById(id)
          var wrappedID = angular.element(queryResult);
         // alert(wrappedID);
          return wrappedID;
        };
       dumb('myAudio').addClass('active'); 
       dumb('myAudio')[0].src=$scope.QuestionAudio;
       dumb('myAudio')[0].play();
        dumb('myAudio')[0].onended = function() {
            $scope.audioIndex  += 1;  
            $scope.playAudio($scope.audioIndex); 
        }; 

       console.log('dumb', dumb('myAudio'));
 }
  $scope.playAudio=function(index){    //alert(index);
         $("p > span").removeClass("playing");  
    }
```

I have visited many posts on StackOverflow , but no luck .

Comment: but should it be highlighted word by word without any sense? just looping the highlight among "this" "is" "a" "burger", keeping the highlight few seconds each one? or is there any rule for highlighting?

Comment: highlighted  according to  audio timeline delay  yes few seconds each one